# How do I add an increment of input number on React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, e-commerce

I am building this eCommerce website. I want to increment the product with an input number. I want to output the final increment and multiply with 1 unit of product to calculate the total price. I am new to React js. I used the input number from Antd React. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./CheckoutProduct.css";
import {useStateValue} from "./StateProvider";
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import { InputNumber } from 'antd';


function CheckoutProduct({id, image, title, price, rating}) {
  const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
      const [anchorEl, setAnchorE1] = React.useState(null);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorE1(event.currentTarget);
      };
  const removeFromBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET",
      id: id,
    });
  };
   
  function onChange(value) {
    console.log('changed', value);
    
  }  
  const multiply = (rating, price) => rating * price;

  return (
      <div>
    <div className="checkoutProduct">
      <img className="checkoutProduct__image" src={image} alt="" />
      <div className="checkoutProduct__info">
        <p className="checkoutProduct__title">{title}</p>
        <p className="checkoutProduct__price">
          <small>৳</small>
          <strong>{price}</strong>
          
        </p>
        <InputNumber min={1} max={10} defaultValue={rating} step={1} 
        onChange={addtoBasket}  />
               

      </div>
      
      <ClearIcon className='remove_icon'  onClick={removeFromBasket}></ClearIcon>
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default CheckoutProduct;
```

This is my product code:

```js
import React from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import MediaQuery from "react-responsive";
import './Product_page.css'

function Product_page_mens_new() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="home__container">
          <div className='ad_space'></div>
       
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0001"
            title="Khaki Zip Neck Fleece"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F227498.jpg?alt=media&token=27458e87-2379-41ee-86f3-e5973b6aba75"
            rating={1}
          />
          <Product
            id="0002"
            title="
            Brushed Flannel Check Long Sleeve Shirt"
            price={300}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F265210.jpg?alt=media&token=0265a3cf-4c06-4bee-a32d-ed8c0f56a35b"
            rating={2}
          />
          <Product
            id="0003"
            title="Brown Faux Shearling Flight Jacket"
            price={375}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F291558.jpg?alt=media&token=c4db1e73-f7b0-4ccd-974b-9a56a1c02831"
            rating={3}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0004"
            title="Check Cosy Cuffed Pyjama Set"
            price={2500}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F583408.jpg?alt=media&token=66558eb9-baaf-4b99-88ce-7609ba8dbe9d"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0005"
            title="Smart Dark Blue Straight Fit Jeans"
            price={1400}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F648732.jpg?alt=media&token=d15e452e-38b0-4719-96a5-e124b449c530"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0006"
            title="Navy Matching Family Mens"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F820153.jpg?alt=media&token=561fcb2c-ab5b-4612-8cec-0c07a50a3e68"
            rating={4}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0007"
            title="Navy Borg Lined Dressing Gown"
            price={72000}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F947688.jpg?alt=media&token=c9c5554b-a7e6-44ae-8192-9b26c76d19dc"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0008"
            title="Navy Chest Stripe Pyjama Set"
            price={150}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F953225.jpg?alt=media&token=60f75a78-821f-4875-aa1d-87e6f0a09c27"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0009"
            title="Charcoal Cable Knit Jumper"
            price={250}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F990630.jpg?alt=media&token=7f9fe847-5d48-497c-a3a6-6ff90b468658"
            rating={4}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="home__container_mobile">
          <div className='ad_space'></div>
       
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0001"
            title="Khaki Zip Neck Fleece"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F227498.jpg?alt=media&token=27458e87-2379-41ee-86f3-e5973b6aba75"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0002"
            title="
            Brushed Flannel Check Long Sleeve Shirt"
            price={300}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F265210.jpg?alt=media&token=0265a3cf-4c06-4bee-a32d-ed8c0f56a35b"
            rating={5}
          />
          
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0003"
            title="Brown Faux Shearling Flight Jacket"
            price={375}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F291558.jpg?alt=media&token=c4db1e73-f7b0-4ccd-974b-9a56a1c02831"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0004"
            title="Check Cosy Cuffed Pyjama Set"
            price={2500}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F583408.jpg?alt=media&token=66558eb9-baaf-4b99-88ce-7609ba8dbe9d"
            rating={5}
          />
          
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0005"
            title="Smart Dark Blue Straight Fit Jeans"
            price={1400}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F648732.jpg?alt=media&token=d15e452e-38b0-4719-96a5-e124b449c530"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0006"
            title="Navy Matching Family Mens"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F820153.jpg?alt=media&token=561fcb2c-ab5b-4612-8cec-0c07a50a3e68"
            rating={4}
          />
          
         
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0007"
            title="Navy Borg Lined Dressing Gown"
            price={72000}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F947688.jpg?alt=media&token=c9c5554b-a7e6-44ae-8192-9b26c76d19dc"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0008"
            title="Navy Chest Stripe Pyjama Set"
            price={150}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F953225.jpg?alt=media&token=60f75a78-821f-4875-aa1d-87e6f0a09c27"
            rating={4}
          />
        
        </div>
        <Product
            id="0009"
            title="Charcoal Cable Knit Jumper"
            price={250}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/mens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F990630.jpg?alt=media&token=7f9fe847-5d48-497c-a3a6-6ff90b468658"
            rating={4}
          />
        <div className="home__row">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Product_page_womens_new() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="home__container">
          <div className='ad_space'></div>
       
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0001"
            title="Animal Dolman V-Neck Jumper"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F854461.jpg?alt=media&token=4132c6f1-6868-4e91-bcae-c09dadece319"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0002"
            title="
            Dark Blue Power Stretch Denim "
            price={300}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F228058.jpg?alt=media&token=64a8b160-bb3d-476f-bef7-acde4fe80ee7"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0003"
            title="Grey Gem Button Shoulder Jumper"
            price={375}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F847874.jpg?alt=media&token=05979a94-9f29-4cf2-82b0-e68f72d9fa01"
            rating={5}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0004"
            title="Navy/Yellow Geometric Print Tie Neck"
            price={2500}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F952535.jpg?alt=media&token=7bfd6269-9cee-47a7-86d4-0198785034cc"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0005"
            title="Mid Blue Puff Sleeve Denim Shirt"
            price={1400}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F788378.jpg?alt=media&token=3f6e4225-59cb-42b3-8651-2b186e278cb7"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0006"
            title="Pink Neppy Ruffle Neck Jumper"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F397182.jpg?alt=media&token=8a7fb059-f3d0-4870-ae3c-f144745ac070"
            rating={4}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
          <Product
            id="0007"
            title="Black Floral Flippy Dress"
            price={72000}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F316829.jpg?alt=media&token=31ae75ec-80a6-49c8-808a-df106eaf2908"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0008"
            title="Berry Woven Hem Jumper"
            price={150}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F279076.jpg?alt=media&token=6df4b717-407b-4da8-928a-3cf42ae7846b"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0009"
            title="Sky Blue Forever Soft Boot Cut Jeans"
            price={250}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F203430.jpg?alt=media&token=eb126e67-a970-4af1-ad5b-5583deec086f"
            rating={4}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="home__container_mobile">
          <div className='ad_space'></div>
       
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0001"
            title="Animal Dolman V-Neck Jumper"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F854461.jpg?alt=media&token=4132c6f1-6868-4e91-bcae-c09dadece319"
            rating={5}
          />
          <Product
            id="0002"
            title="
            Dark Blue Power Stretch Denim "
            price={300}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F228058.jpg?alt=media&token=64a8b160-bb3d-476f-bef7-acde4fe80ee7"
            rating={5}
          />
          
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0003"
            title="Grey Gem Button Shoulder Jumper"
            price={375}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F847874.jpg?alt=media&token=05979a94-9f29-4cf2-82b0-e68f72d9fa01"
            rating={5}
          />
         <Product
            id="0004"
            title="Navy/Yellow Geometric Print Tie Neck"
            price={2500}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F952535.jpg?alt=media&token=7bfd6269-9cee-47a7-86d4-0198785034cc"
            rating={5}
          />
          
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0005"
            title="Mid Blue Puff Sleeve Denim Shirt"
            price={1400}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F788378.jpg?alt=media&token=3f6e4225-59cb-42b3-8651-2b186e278cb7"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0006"
            title="Pink Neppy Ruffle Neck Jumper"
            price={450}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F397182.jpg?alt=media&token=8a7fb059-f3d0-4870-ae3c-f144745ac070"
            rating={4}
          />
          
         
        </div>
        <div className="home__row">
        <Product
            id="0007"
            title="Black Floral Flippy Dress"
            price={72000}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F316829.jpg?alt=media&token=31ae75ec-80a6-49c8-808a-df106eaf2908"
            rating={4}
          />
          <Product
            id="0008"
            title="Berry Woven Hem Jumper"
            price={150}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F279076.jpg?alt=media&token=6df4b717-407b-4da8-928a-3cf42ae7846b"
            rating={4}
          />
        
        </div>
        <Product
            id="0009"
            title="Sky Blue Forever Soft Boot Cut Jeans"
            price={250}
            image="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/iflexmart.appspot.com/o/womens%20cloth-%20new%20in%2F203430.jpg?alt=media&token=eb126e67-a970-4af1-ad5b-5583deec086f"
            rating={4}
          />
        <div className="home__row">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export {
  Product_page_mens_new,
  Product_page_womens_new
}
```

I also have a reducer

```js
export const initialState = {
    basket: [],
    user: null,
  };
  
  //Selector
  
  export const getBasketTotal = (basket) =>
    basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
        return {
          ...state,
          basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
        };
      case "REMOVE_FROM_BASKET":
        const index = state.basket.findIndex(
          (basketItem) => basketItem.id === action.id
        );
        let newBasket = [...state.basket];
        if (index >= 0) {
          newBasket.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          console.warn(`cant remove (id: ${action.id})`);
        }
        return {
          ...state,
          basket: newBasket,
        };
      case "SET_USER":
        return {
          ...state,
          user: action.user,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where your `addToBasket` function is defined, basically this would typically be the setter of a `useState` hook like so :

```
function CheckoutProduct() {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

  return (
    <InputNumber min={1} max={10} defaultValue={1} step={1} 
                 onChange={setQuantity} />
  )
}
```

Then antd `InputNumber` has it own increment, so you should see it and it should work like so.
Since you seem to store your basket in your Redux store, you can make perform the multiplication by the unit price in your reducer when the user confirms the order.

Comment: I deployed the build. If you buy from this page then go to the cart, you will see a product increment. I just want the subtotal to change accordingly.   https://fervent-lamarr-d068fc.netlify.app/mens-new